# ORA-29275: partial multibyte character

Tags: sql, oracle

I have input data coming from a flat file which has english, japanese, chinese characters in one column.
I am loading these values in a staging table column whose schema definition is VARCHAR2(250 CHAR),  the main table column has definition VARCHAR2(250) WHICH i can not change.
So, i am doing a SUBSTR on this column. After loading the table when i did a

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE
```

...I get this error :

> ORA-29275: partial multibyte character

If i select other columns then no issues.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you should use `SUBSTRB` when you copy your data from your `250 CHAR` column to your `250 byte` column. This function will only output whole characters (you won't get incomplete unicode characters):

```
SQL> select substrb('中华人', 1, 9) ch9,
  2         substrb('中华人', 1, 8) ch8,
  3         substrb('中华人', 1, 7) ch7,
  4         substrb('中华人', 1, 6) ch6,
  5         substrb('中华人', 1, 5) ch5
  6    FROM dual;

CH9       CH8      CH7     CH6    CH5
--------- -------- ------- ------ -----
中华人       中华       中华      中华     中
```

#### Edit:

[@mwardm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/52840/mwardm) made an interesting comment concerning the actual length of the resulting string and whether the resulting string could contain an invalid sequence of bytes. Consider the following on an AL32UTF8 DB:

```
SQL> select lengthb('ÏÏÏ'),
  2         lengthb(substrb('ÏÏÏÏÏÏ', 1, 5)),
  3         dump('ÏÏÏ'),
  4         dump(substrb('ÏÏÏÏÏÏ', 1, 5))
  5    FROM dual;

LE LE DUMP('ÏÏÏ')                           DUMP(SUBSTRB('ÏÏÏÏÏÏ',1,5))
-- -- ------------------------------------- -------------------------------
 6  5 Typ=96 Len=6: 195,143,195,143,195,143 Typ=1 Len=5: 195,143,195,143,32
```

As you can see the last byte of the `substrb` string is not the truncated first byte of the special character but encodes a legit character (The first 128 characters in this character set are the same as the ASCII7US character set so this encodes the `' '` space character, using RTRIM as suggested in another answer will remove the last character).

Furthermore, I also got this interesting result using the character set AL16UTF16:

```
SQL> select lengthb(N'ĈĈ') le,
  2         dump(N'ĈĈ') dump,
  3         lengthb(substrb(N'Ĉ', 1, 3)) length_substr,
  4         dump(substrb(N'ĈĈ', 1, 3)) dump_substr
  5    from dual;

        LE DUMP                    LENGTH_SUBSTR DUMP_SUBSTR
---------- ----------------------- ------------- -----------------
         4 Typ=96 Len=4: 1,8,1,8               2 Typ=1 Len=2: 1,8
```

In this case Oracle has choosen to cut the string after the second byte because in the AL16UTF16 character set there is no legit one-byte character. The resulting string is only 2 bytes instead of 3.

This would need further testing and is by no mean a rigorous demonstration but I still stand by my first hunch that `substrb` will return a valid sequence of bytes that encodes a valid string of characters.

Comment: Shouldn't that be substrc?  substrb copies in bytes and can truncate an extended character.

Comment: @Jim: the column will have to be truncated, a `250 CHAR` column may possibly have as much as 1000 bytes of data, it won't fit in a `250 byte` column. The function will not cut a UTF-8 character in half however: the result will always be a legal UTF-8 string.

Comment: @Vincent:   Doesn't seem to be true that it won't cut a character in half - if you wrap a lengthb around your ch8 and ch7 columns then I'd wager you're going to get 8 and 7 back respectively.  (In 11g anyway.)  I suspect that, probably because of the clever way they defined the character encoding, the partial character generally just isn't printable and so is ignored.

Comment: ... [I have a vague plan to try to correctly trim the odd byte off by, after the substrb, using a (character-based) length (which will presumably ignore the odd-byte too) and then character-based substr-inging to that length.... but hey, it's just about the weekend and this question is getting on for its two year anniversary!]

Comment: @mwardm: that's interesting, I hadn't thought that the output could be an invalid string of bytes (since it is varchar2) yet could be displayed properly. I don't have access to a database right now but I'll have a look when I can (not this weekend probably though :)

Comment: @mwardm: confirming your "wager". just tested it and indeed lengthb does return 9,8,7,6,5.  my "wager" then is that if you store this in a utf-8 charset db, after substrb, it'll use the "invalid/unknown" character to substitute for the invalid trailing bytes, which is, AFAIK, a 2-byte sequence, so the substrb(7) will end up 8-bytes once stored in a utf8 column.

Comment: @dmansfield I still think `substrb`will retrun a legit VARCHAR2 string, see my updated answer.

Comment: I enjoy the fact that this answer has the term "LE DUMP" in it: https://i.stack.imgur.com/id2Im.png

Answer (score 2):

I think i might have found a good way to do it
if you do `rtrim(substrb('中华人', 1, 8))` you get `'中华'` and a byte length of the expected 6

please try

Comment: Thanks Taryn. It helped me resolve the issue.
SourceDB- UTF8
Target DB- AL32UTF8
Was gettting the error:
ORA-29275: partial multibyte character

Answer (score 0):

Using substr will behave differently depending on the database character set.  I assume from your description that your DB character set is not one of the Unicode variants, and you must truncate the varchar2(250 char) data to 250 BYTES or less.  This is dangerous because it can stop in the middle of a 2-byte character, resulting in the message you got.  You should look at the documentation for substrc(), which will calculate its length based on characters and not bytes.

It might help if you explain more why you are required to throw away part of the data.

Comment: the description column in source system allowed creating strings which are very long, and the data file is extracted from source system, but the target system does not allow more than 250 bytes. chinese characters are taking more than one byte, which is creating the problem, the ETL tool i am using to load is informatica, it does not have full oracle functions supported.I will check if substrc() is available.